# Data from parent to children coming with delay in react

Tags: reactjs, frontend, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to pass data from the parent component to the child but the data is coming with a delay which broke my code. This is the child component and the second is the parent. What did I do wrong?
The data should be passed to the child before the rendering in App.js. How to fix it?

The problem is in 'const rows = objectProps' in the Grid component. The data is coming with a delay

```
import React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import "./Grid.css";
    
const Grid = ({objectProps}) => {
  
  const rows = objectProps
 
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", hide: true },
    { field: "empId1", headerName: "Employee ID#1", width: 150 },
    { field: "empId2", headerName: "Employee ID#2", width: 150 },
    { field: "projectId", headerName: "Project ID", width: 150 },
    { field: "days", headerName: "Days worked", width: 150 },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="data-grid-container">
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Grid;
```

And this is the parent component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import readLines from './helpers/calculateTeamDays'
import InputFile from "../src/components/input/InputFile";
import Grid from "../src/components/grid/Grid";


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const [showGrid, setShowGrid] = useState(false);
  const [none, setNone] = useState(false);

  

  const addFile = (e) => {
    let fileList = e.target.files;
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {

      let linesArray = fileReader.result.split("\n")

      let objects = readLines(linesArray);
      objects.forEach((obj, i) => obj.id = i)

      if (objects) {
        setShowGrid(true)
        setState(objects)
        setNone(false)
        console.table(objects)

      } else {
        setNone(true)
        setShowGrid(false)
       }
    }

    fileReader.readAsText(fileList[0])
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Find two team members worked longest on project together</h1>

      <InputFile add={addFile} />
      {none ? <h2>No one worked in a team!</h2> : null}
      {showGrid ? <Grid objectProps={state} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The easiest way to go about this is to ensure that your `state` object is not empty prior to rendering the `Grid` component. `showGrid` may be `true` prior to the `state` object being populated with properties, since all those `useState` update functions are asynchronous, and depending how `React` batches them, you can never expect them to run in order in which they were called.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import readLines from './helpers/calculateTeamDays'
import InputFile from "../src/components/input/InputFile";
import Grid from "../src/components/grid/Grid";


function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const addFile = (e) => {
    let fileList = e.target.files;
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {

      let linesArray = fileReader.result.split("\n")

      let objects = readLines(linesArray);
      objects.forEach((obj, i) => obj.id = i)

      if (objects) {    
        setState(objects)
      } else {
setState(null) 
}
    }

    fileReader.readAsText(fileList[0])
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Find two team members worked longest on project together</h1>
      <InputFile add={addFile} />
      {state && Object.entires(state).length > 0 ?
       <Grid objectProps={state} /> : 
        <h2>No one worked in a team!</h2>} 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: No the delay still crashing the app. I think I need send the data before rendering but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: updated with all the code, please let me know if its still happeninng

Comment: No, now I get error object.entries is not a function
Here is the source code https://github.com/xakepa/FirstName-LastName-employees

The program input file is plain text file with names. For example 
Frank, proectX, 2020-01-01, 2021-02-03
Frank, ASD, 2017-01-01, 2019-02-03
Ivan, ASD, 2018-01-01, 2018-06-03
Martin, ASD, 2020-3-2, 2020-3-6
Frank, ASD, 2020-3-20, 2020-3-25
Frank, OI9, 2017-3-7, 2020-3-25
Ivan, proectX, 2020-01-01, 2021-02-03

Comment: @Simba there's a typo in the code above, should be `Object.entries(state)`, but you also might be running this in a browser that doesn't support `Object.entries`, which in that case I suggest using the `Object.keys` method.

Comment: I had to remove object.entries() and now it works
 {state && state.length > 0 ? (
        <Grid objectProps={state} />